# Handle reconnection/retries using Lyra-style in Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp

I am using RabbitMQ covered with Spring AMQP abstraction.
So in essence I am using Spring AMQP.

I need to handle conneciton failures. It's fairly easy to achieve this using [Lyra](https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra) when you use raw RabbitMQ classes.

How do you achieve the same in Spring AMQP? **I want my code to be unaware of any network problems**.

I know Spring handles reconnections by default (in some way), but what I want is a Lyra-style configuration (be it in XML or wherever), so I can define timeout, max retries, backoff etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the consuming side there is no way to configure that - the container will simply retry the connection on a fixed schedule; configurable by setting `recoveryInterval` in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` which defaults to 5 seconds. There's not much value in configuring a backoff for consumers.

On the publishing side, you can use `spring-aop` to wrap the RabbitTemplate (AmqpTemplate interface) in a `MethodInterceptor` that wraps the `send*()` calls in a `RetryTemplate` from [spring-retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry). The `RetryTemplate` can be configured with all sorts of options, including backoff policy etc.

If you need help with that, I can try to find some time to post a Gist.

EDIT:

Per the comment below - correct, the `recoveryInterval` is currently not available with the namespace (but you can still define the container as a `<bean ... class="...SimpleMessageListenerContainer...>`.

However, it was added a few weeks ago to the master branch ([commit here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/commit/43251642bf2208592f389c9d0b7fa7ee220f9ae9#diff-4)). It is available in the 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

Also, as a result of your question here, I have added a `RetryTemplate` option to the `RabbitTemplate` ([pull request here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/171)). It should be merged soon. The release candidate for 1.3.0 (1.3.0.RC1) is due Friday and the 1.3.0 GA release will follow within a couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks for covering both sides. If a publisher gist was not a problem, I'd really appreciate it. I think other visitors could too, since there isn't that many examples online..

Comment: Also, please correct me if I'm wrong, but the XML version of container, `<rabbit:listener-container>` cannot have a `recoveryInterval` configured.. ?

Comment: OK, thanks! One more thing: can you **mix** `<rabbit>` tags with standard `<bean>` (i.e. use both to configure rabbitMQ in a single app) and expect they will work just as all have been defined with the same namespace?

Comment: Yes, you can mix and match; all the Spring namespace parsers end up generating bean definitions.

Comment: @GaryRussell what relation is between connectionTimeout that is set to ConnectionFactory and RetryTemplate policies?

Comment: There is no relationship - the retry template doesn't know anything about what is being retried. Any retry delays in the policy will start when the exception occurs (which is generally after the timeout expires).